# Specifying spring reference by type in XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

Say I have the following class:

```
@Service
public class Foo {

    @Autowired    
    private MySvcClass svc;
}
```

If I use Spring's annotation initialization, Spring will iterate through all of its beans and if it has a single instance of `MySvcClass`, it will inject it.  I don't need to know the name of the instance of `MySvcClass`, just that it's an instance of `MySvcClass`.

How do I get the same result if I'm using the XML and not leveraging annotations?

For instance by xml def could look like:

```
<bean id="foo" class="Foo">
   <property name="svc" ref="idOfMySvcClass"/>
</bean>
```

But this requires me to know the name of the `MySvcClass` instance.  Is there a way for Spring to use the same logic as above where I specify only the type and Spring will find my instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need not have to know the bean names, you can use 'autowiring by-type'.

Your XML configuration will look like this:

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.example.Foo" autowire="byType" />

<bean id="mySvcClass" class="com.example.MySvcClass" />
```

Note the 'autowire by type' attribute at Foo class.

The class definition will look like below:

```
package com.example;

public class Foo 
{
    private MySvcClass mySvcClass;

}
```

Comment: this way all dependencies have to be wired by type, but if I want just 1 of many?

Answer (score 2):

Add autowire="byType" attribute to your bean element in xml.